# Whitelisting network requests from a particular domain in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am creating a Chrome extension that allows users to block websites by either blacklisting a set of sites and allowing the rest; or the opposite, whitelisting a select few sites and blocking the rest.

I am achieving this through the [webRequest Chrome API using onBeforeWebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

The challenge I am facing is that when I whitelist a website, for example www.reddit.com I can successfully allow the user to visit Reddit, but all the network requests it relies on (images, etc) are delivered through various domains which are obvious caught by the blocker: redd.it, redditmedia.com, redditstatic.com

Is there any good way to allow all requests to/from the domains in my whitelist?

---

EDIT:

I just found that you can filter out based on resource type as per [API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-ResourceType). So I am only applying my filter to only "main_frame" which appears to be letting everything through as I was hoping. If anyone has any input on if this is not a good idea, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that you can filter out based on resource type as per API docs. So I am only applying my filter to only "main_frame" which appears to be letting everything through as I was hoping. If anyone has any input on if this is not a good idea, I'd love to know.